# Multiplication of summations

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The length of the following equation depends on the value of the variable `n`. How can I write this equation? How can I reformulate it?

$$f(n)=x+y\cdot\sum_{a=1}^{n}\left(x+y\cdot\sum_{b=1}^{n-1}\left(x+y\cdot\sum_{c=1}^{n-2}\left(x+y\cdot\sum_{d=1}^{n-3}....\right)\right)\right)$$

Moreover I'd need that the sum $\sum_{1}^{1}$ equals 0!

for example:

$$f(3)=x+y\cdot\sum_{a=1}^{3}\left(x+y\cdot\sum_{b=1}^{2}\left(x+y\cdot\sum_{c=1}^{1}\left(x+y\cdot0\right)\right)\right)$$

UPDATE

Re-written differently I think it gives. But still, the length of my equation depends on the value of `n`

$$f(n)=x+y \cdot (n \cdot x + n \cdot y \cdot ((n-1)\cdot x + (n-1) \cdot y \cdot ((n-2)\cdot x + (n-2)\cdot y \cdot (....)) ))$$

for example:

$$f(3)=x+y \cdot (3 \cdot x + 3 \cdot y \cdot ((2)\cdot x + (2) \cdot y \cdot ((1)\cdot x + (1)\cdot y \cdot 0)))$$

Thank you!

Comment: Take $n=4$ or $5$ and unwrap it. You wll get something simple in powers of $y$.

Comment: What is $\sum x$? Is it $\sum x_i$?

Comment: @Kaster no x is x (a constant value). Therefore the variables a, b c, d are not used in the formulas. They deserve only to indicate the number of iteration, or the number of terms in the sum. Does it make sense?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you tell me more about that please?

Comment: On looking at it more closely, I see that the meaning og your expressiion is not clear. Look at the leftmost $\sum$ symbol. Are we just supposed to add the number $x$ to itself $n$ times? That is the overt meaning, but it may not be what you intend. Does this leftmost $\sum$ encompass all the complicated stuff to the right of it? In that case there are missing brackets. It would be best if an example were added, say with $n=3$, and everything absolutely explicit.

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't $\sum x = nx$, if $x = const$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok, I understand my parentheses problem. Thanks for your help. I corrected it. Indeed the leftmost $\sum$ encompass all the stuff on its left.

Comment: @Kaster It's a matter of parentheses. I fixed the problem. Hope it makes sense now!

Comment: if the expression under the summation does not change with the summation-index (a,b,c,...) then the sum can be replaced by writing n-times the expression, where n is the upper summation index. You'll see how this simplifies dramatically...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms according to your comment, I updated my post. Is it correct? What can I do from that?

Comment: @Remi: very well. But now proceed one more step and do the multiplications and collect the $x,y,x\cdot y,...$ terms and having 3,4 examples with $f(2),f(3),f(4), ...$ I think you'll see the pattern emerging. After that - when one has a firm impression of that pattern it should be possible to prove it (and possibly express it by a sum of *fixed* length of factorials, binomials or similar)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that summing $m$ times the same thing amounts tom multiplying it by $m$, you get
$$
  f(n)=x+yn(x+y(n-1)(x+y(n-2)(\cdots(x+y.1(x+0y))\ldots)))
$$
which resembles a polynomial in $y$ expressed by a Horner scheme; you get
$$
\begin{align}
  f(n)&=x+xny+xn(n-1)y+n(n-1)(n-2)y^3x+\cdots+n(n-1)\ldots2xy^{n-1}+n!xy^n
\\ &=x\sum_{i=0}^nn^{\underline i}y^i
\end{align}
$$
where $n^{\underline i}$ denotes the falling factorial power.

Comment: THanks a lot! $n^{\underline 1}=n$, $n^{\underline 2}=n*(n-1)$ What does $n^{\underline 0}$ equals to?

Comment: Like any empty product, $n^{\underline 0}$ equals$~1$ (even when $n=0$ ;-).

Comment: I'm asking a second question. What if the very first `x` (and only the very first `x`) of my series was divided by two? It would give: $\frac{x}{2}+x\sum_{i=1}^{n}n^{\underline {i}}\cdot y^i$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, just subtract $x/2$ from the previous result.